# XML via database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml

I have a list of strings,the list is constant and won't be changed, there are 12 strings.

Inside database table I have a column with an index to the string.
I don't think it's wise to hold a separate table to hold those strings because they never get changed neither to save the string it self inside this column.

So the only option is to hold the list in some other type.

What about holding the strings in XML file and using Linq-to-Xml to load them into dictionary. 
If so is thi better, performance wise, then using datatable?

Comment: what will these strings be used for? Why not use a resource file or the config?

Comment: definition of the product, there are 12 product types (constant and never get changed), so when user asks for a product he  needs to get the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those strings will most likely get cached by your SQL server and apply almost no performance hit. But will give you a flexibility in case you have multiple applications sharing same database. Overall keep those in the database unless you have/expect millions database hits.

Comment: so, I should place them in a separate table (even if they are constant) and retrieve them via JOIN when user request entry from the database that contains the index(foreign key)?

Comment: Yes, they can be referenced by their IDs in other tables

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Zepplock, keep the strings in the database. You won´t have to worry about performance.  One of the big reason is also that if you do so, it will easier for future developers to find the strings and understand their function within the application if you store them in the database in their proper context.

Comment: Playing devil's advocate: if he stores this information in an XML file within his codebase, it will have versioning history along with the rest of the code if it is ever changed.

Comment: Are you saying one should stick with xml on the grounds that versioning is easier.  If versioning of the strings are a requirement it can be very easily implemented in the database.  Database is best at storing data, if the strings are related to the content of the application they should be with the data.  Versioning it in a version control system with code is not my preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you're describing a table holding product catalog data. Suggest keeping those values in their own rows, and not stored as an XML datatype or in XML in a varchar column.

It sounds as if the data is static today, and rarely if ever, is changed. By storing in XML, you lose the potential future advantage of the relational nature of the database.

Suggest keeping them in a table. As you say, it's only 12 strings/products, and the performance hit will be zero.